# Trying to push an object into array, array is undefined

Tags: javascript

Simple question, Provided that 'dish' is a standard object from the same type. Why is the push not possible??

```
 class DinnerModel {
  constructor() {
    this.menu = new Array();
    this.dishes = dishesConst;
    this.guests = this.setNumberOfGuests(1);
  }

  addDishToMenu(dish) {
    menu.push(dish);
  }
```

I get the error message:

```
  ReferenceError: menu is not defined
    at DinnerModel.addDishToMenu (src/model/dinnerModel.js:76:5)
    at Context.<anonymous> (src/model/dinnerModel.test.js:204:15)
```

Comment: `menu` !== `this.menu`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple- you forgot to use `this` in `addDishToMenu`:

this would work:

```
addDishToMenu(dish) {
  this.menu.push(dish);
}
```

also, as a side note- instead of using `new Array()` you can just initialize it to `[]`.